# How do I get this to iterate correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to place information about X number of victims.
First input how many victims.
Next input "name", "age" and "social media" for each victim.
Last to write it all to a file.

A victim can have more than 1 instagram account or more than 1 snapchat account, and I would like to be able to input Instagram 1, Instagram 2, Instagram 3, ect. for each victim and get back to the "menu" to choose more social media accounts to input for the given victim.

Something goes wrong when I'm iterating through this. Fx. for each instagram account I add it doesn't count up +1.

Also I do not get the option to input social media for victim 2, 3, 4 ect. It just skip it and end the script.

I am probably approaching this all wrong, why I seek help to learn the right way. :)

```
# SOCIAL MEDIA
instagram = []
snapchat = []
twitter = []
youtube = []
other = []
social_media = True


# Get input of victims.
number_of_victims = int(input("How many victims: "))
confirm_social_media = input("\nAny social media? y or n: ")
victim_names = []
victim_ages = []
if confirm_social_media == "n":
    for i in range(1, number_of_victims + 1):
        victim_names.append(input("Name of victim " + str(i) + ": "))
        victim_ages.append(input("Age of victim " + str(i) + ": "))
    print(victim_names, victim_ages)
else:
    for i in range(1, number_of_victims + 1):
        victim_names.append(input("Name of victim " + str(i) + ": "))
        victim_ages.append(input("Age of victim " + str(i) + ": "))
        while social_media != "":
            social_media = input("\nType of social media: "
                                 "\n'i' = Instagram"
                                 "\n's' = Snapchat"
                                 "\n't' = Twitter"
                                 "\n'y' = Youtube"
                                 "\n'o' = Other"
                                 "\nOr blank for next")
            snumbr = 1
            if social_media == 'i':
                iinput = input("Instagram " + str(snumbr) + ": ")
                instagram.append(iinput)

            elif social_media == 's':
                sinput = input("Snapchat " + str(snumbr) + ": ")
                instagram.append(sinput)
                snumbr += 1
    print(victim_names, victim_ages, instagram, snapchat)

# Write victims to file.
for v in range(number_of_victims):
    target.write("__Victim " + str(v + 1) + ":__\n")
    target.write("- Name: " + victim_names[v] + "\n")
    target.write("- Estimated age: " + victim_ages[v] + " years old.\n\n")
    target.write("- Instagram: " + instagram[v] + "\n")
    target.write("- Snapchat: " + snapchat[v] + "\n")
```

Comment: Look at your indentation. You only execute `snumbr += 1` when you picked `s`.

Comment: You also set `snumbr = 1` *inside* your loop, so it'll always be set to 1. You can't increment a number you keep resetting back. Put that line *outside* your `while` loop.

Comment: Next, you never reset the `social_media` variable, so it'll still be set to an empty string. Move the `social_media = True` into the loop for victims.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot.
I can't figure out how to test for confirm_social_media to run or skip the social media question loop, in the victim counts loop. 

Also I am encountering a new problem. If the user fx. only input an instagram account, but leave out the snapchat, then I get the error:

`    target.write("- Snapchat: " + snapchat[v] + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range `

Comment: Right, but you only append to `instagram`, never to `snapchat`. You also don't account for the possibility that no social media accounts were entered. Your printing code assumes that the number of victims == the number of social media entries.

Comment: I've added a better approach below.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am lost in how to use the first part of your approach. Should I use it with my existing " for i in range(1, number_of_victims + 1): " loop and define a victims = [] list ?? I have tried playing around for about 50 minutes, but I am lost :))))

Comment: I get     `target.write("__Victim " + victim['number'] + ":__\n")
TypeError: must be str, not int`

Comment: Right, because I forgot to use `str()` there, to convert the integer to a string representation. But I'm sure you had figured that out yourself already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166319/discussion-between-aquatic7-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making 3 mistakes:

1. Your `while` loop tests for `social_media != ""`. That's true the first time because you set `social_media = True` at the top. But you ask the user to end the loop by leaving the input blank. You never reset that setting, so for the *next* victim, `social_media = ""` is *still there*.

   Either set `social_media` to a different value for every victim, or don't use a flag at all, just use `while True:` and *after* asking for the input, use `break` if the input was empty:

   ```
   while True:
       social_media = input(...)
       if not social_media:  # empty
           break

       # ...
   ```
2. You set your counter to 1 **inside** the social media loop. So for every social media entry, you set the counter *back to 1*. Set the counter to 1 **outside** the loop:

   ```
   snumbr = 1
   while ...:
       # ask for social media

       # done asking, increment
       snumbr += 1
   ```
3. You only increment the number when you asked for a snapchat account. You need to increment the number regardless of what account you asked for.

Your structure could be better; it's a bit weird that you test for `confirm_social_media` first then repeat the same `for` loop. Just loop over the victim counts, and *in that loop*, test for `confirm_social_media` to run or skip the social media question loop.

You really want to rethink your printing strategy too, because your code assumes that each victim will have exactly one instagram and one snapchat account. That's not the case, you need to create a *list* of social media accounts per victim.

You should use a dictionary per victim instead, and store the dictionary in the list. Use a single `victims` list, and in the per-victim loop, use:

```
victim_data = {'number': i}
victim_data['name'] = input("Name of victim " + str(i) + ": ")
victim_data['age'] = input("Age of victim " + str(i) + ": ")
instagram = victim_data['instagram'] = []
snapchat = victim_data['snapchat'] = []

# collect social media in `instagram` and `snapchat`

victims.append(victim_data)
```

then loop over the list of dictionaries and print out the data you collected:

```
for victim in victims:
    target.write("__Victim " + str(victim['number']) + ":__\n")
    target.write("- Name: " + victim['name'] + "\n")
    target.write("- Estimated age: " + victim['age'] + " years old.\n\n")
    for account in victim['instagram']:
        target.write("- Instagram: " + account + "\n")
    for account in victim['snapchat']:
        target.write("- Snapchat: " + account + "\n")
```